# Inserir dados de vários formulários sem refresh com ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, formulário

Bom dia! estou com problema em uma aplicação, o que acontece; 1 - eu tenho esse cara que recebe o nome do produto e mostra minha lista:

```
var req;

function buscarProd(valor) {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var url = "system/pedidos/data.php?valor=" + valor;

req.open("Get", url, true);

req.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = '<div class="buscprod">Buscando produto...</div>';
    }

    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

        var resposta = req.responseText;

        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
}
req.send(null);
```

}

junto com esse:

```
$Valor = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valor', FILTER_DEFAULT);
if (empty($Valor)):
 exit;
endif;
$Like = "%{$Valor}%";
$Read = new Read;
$Read->ExeRead("produto", "WHERE descricao LIKE :val ORDER BY descricao ASC", "val={$Like}");

foreach ($Read->getResult() as $Produtos):
?>
<form name="FormProd" id="FormProd" method="post" action="#">
    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">


        <tr><td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Produtos['codigo']; ?>" name="codpro"/></td></tr>

        <tr> 
            <td colspan="3">

                <?php echo $Produtos['descricao']; ?>

            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td colspan="1">
                <input style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;" name="qntpro" type="number" placeholder="Qnt" />
            <td> 
            <td style="display: none"><input name="nome_usu" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userlogin['nome_usu']; ?>"/></td>
            <td style="width: 60px;">
                <input type="submit" name="btnForm" class="circleCar right icon-add" value="Add"/>
                <!--<div class="icon-add"></div>-->
            <td>

    </table>
</form>   

<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

O problema é que quando eu pesquiso um produto aparece diversos em abaixo com o mesmo seguimento de letras que digitei na pesquisa, até aí tudo bem, eu coloco a quantidade em 1 produto e dou um add, a pagina da um refresh e adiciono esse produto em minha tabela e faço a pesquisa novamente e add outro, e outro e outro, porém as vezes eu pesquiso e já vejo de cara 3 produtos que quero, só que não posso cadastra os 3 de uma vez pois minha pagina da um refresh, eu queria fazer isso com ajax, so que o ajax parece não funciona nesse método, pois já tentei usar o `e.preventDefault()` return false e ele continua atualizando a pagina, alguém pode me ajudar?

Lembrando, estou dando o foreach em um formulário, ou seja cada produto está em 1 formulario com um input pra por sua quantidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você está adicionando um elemento, dinamicamente. Caso você esteja tratando o clique do botão ou o envio do formulário antes dele, realmente, ser adicionado na página, a função irá falhar.

Há três formas de você trabalhar com funções para elementos dinâmicos:

- *Criar/Recriar* na função *Observer (callback)* do [xmlhttprequest](/questions/tagged/xmlhttprequest) na página *PHP*
- Utilizar o método `on` do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)
- Caso esteja utilizando [vanilla](/questions/tagged/vanilla), você poderá criar um *Observer* para os eventos de *submit* no elemento `body`.

---

### Vamos aos exemplos.

Todos os exemplos serão comentados.

---

#### Exemplo com `Vanilla`

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            /**
             * Função anônima para requisições
             *
             * @param args Object. Ex: {
             *    url:        String,
             *    method:     String,
             *    postfields: FormData|String|Null,
             *    callback:   Function
             *}
             */
            const request = function( args ) {
                const { url, method, postfields, callback } = args

                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.addEventListener("load", callback);
                xhr.open(method, url, true);
                xhr.send(postfields);
            }

            /**
             * Cria uma função de callback
             * Toda vez que ocorrer um evento `submit` no "body"
             * ou em algum elemento filho, essa função será
             * engatilhada.
             */
            document.querySelector("body").addEventListener( "submit", event => {
                event.preventDefault();

                request({
                    url: 'https://stackoverflow.dev/insert',
                    method: 'POST',
                    postfields: new FormData(event.target),
                    callback: result => alert( result.target.response )
                })
            })

            /**
             * Utiliza a função de request para carregar a página
             * do formulário
             */
            request({
                url: 'https://stackoverflow.dev/load-form',
                method: 'GET',
                postfields: null,
                callback: function(result) {
                    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result.target.response)
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Exemplo com `jQuery`

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>            
            /**
             * Cria uma função de callback no elemento body
             * Toda vez que ocorrer um evento `submit` algum 
             * elemento filho, do tipo "form", essa função será
             * engatilhada.
             */
            $("body").on("submit", "form", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.post("https://stackoverflow.dev/insert", $(this).serialize(), function(result) {
                    alert( result )
                })
            })

            /**
             * Utiliza a função de request para carregar a página
             * do formulário
             */
            $("body").load("https://stackoverflow.dev/load-form");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Caso você já utilize *JQuery* em seu projeto, esse exemplo é bom, considerando a quantidade de linhas.

---

#### Retornando o HTML com a função JavaScript

```
<?php
$Valor = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'valor', FILTER_DEFAULT);
if (empty($Valor)):
 exit;

endif;
$Like = "%{$Valor}%";
$Read = new Read;
$Read->ExeRead("produto", "WHERE descricao LIKE :val ORDER BY descricao ASC", "val={$Like}");

foreach ($Read->getResult() as $Produtos):

$id = uniqid();
?>
<form name="FormProd" id="<?php echo "FormProd{$id}" ?>" method="post" action="#">
    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">


        <tr><td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Produtos['codigo']; ?>" name="codpro"/></td></tr>

        <tr> 
            <td colspan="3">

                <?php echo $Produtos['descricao']; ?>

            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td colspan="1">
                <input style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;" name="qntpro" type="number" placeholder="Qnt" />
            <td> 
            <td style="display: none"><input name="nome_usu" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userlogin['nome_usu']; ?>"/></td>
            <td style="width: 60px;">
                <input type="submit" name="btnForm" class="circleCar right icon-add" value="Add"/>
                <!--<div class="icon-add"></div>-->
            <td>

    </table>
</form>

<script>
    /* Cria uma função para eventos de submit do formulário */
    $("#<?php echo "FormProd{$id}" ?>").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post("https://stackoverflow.dev/insert", $(this).serialize(), function(result) {
            alert( result )
        })
    })
</script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> A desvantagem dessa última opção é que você criará vários `scripts`. Isso irá deixar a página muito grande.